# Postgres pl/pgsql ERROR: column "column_name" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

i have a storerd procedure like below,

```
CREATE FUNCTION select_transactions3(text, text, int)    
RETURNS SETOF transactions AS   
$body$   
DECLARE    
    rec transactions%ROWTYPE;  
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT invoice_no, trans_date FROM transactions WHERE $1 = $2 limit $3  )    
    LOOP     
        RETURN NEXT rec;    
    END LOOP;  
END;   
$body$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

when i execute query like this :

```
select * from select_transactions3("invoice_no", '1103300105472',10);
```

or

```
select * from select_transactions3(invoice_no, '1103300105472',10);
```

it getting error like this : 
**ERROR:  column "invoice_no" does not exist**

but when i try execute with one colon like this :

```
select * from select_transactions3('invoice_no', '1103300105472',10);
```

the result is no row.

how i can get the data like this :

```
  invoice_no   |       trans_date        
---------------+-------------------------
 1103300105472 | 2011-03-30 12:25:35.694
```

thanks .

UPDATE : If we want a certain column of table that we want to show

```
CREATE FUNCTION select_to_transactions14(_col character varying, _val character varying, _limit int) 
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
$$
DECLARE
 rec record;
BEGIN
 FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT invoice_no, amount FROM transactions
                 WHERE  ' || _col || ' = $1 LIMIT $2' USING _val, _limit            LOOP
  RETURN NEXT rec;
 END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

to get the result :

```
SELECT * FROM select_to_transactions14( 'invoice_no', '1103300105472',1)
as ("invoice_no" varchar(125), "amount" numeric(12,2));
```

Comment: You're going to need to rewrite it to [execute a dynamic command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN): you have to build the query as a string and then run it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function could look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION select_transactions3(_col text, _val text, _limit int)    
  RETURNS SETOF transactions AS   
$BODY$   
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
   SELECT *
   FROM   transactions
   WHERE  ' || quote_ident(_col) || ' = $1
   LIMIT  $2'
USING _val, _limit;

END;   
$BODY$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

IN PostgreSQL **9.1** or later that's simpler with [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)

```
...
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
   SELECT *
   FROM   transactions
   WHERE  %I = $1
   LIMIT  $2', _col)
USING _val, _limit;
...
```

`%I` escapes identifiers like `quote_ident()`.

#### Major points:

- You were bumping into the limitation of dynamic SQL that you cannot use parameters for identifiers. You have to build the query string with the column name and *then* execute it.
- You can do that with values though. I demonstrate the use of the `USING` clause for `EXECUTE`. Also note the use of [`quote_ident()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER): prevents SQL injection and certain syntax errors.
- I also largely simplified your function. `[RETURN QUERY EXECUTE][3]` makes your code shorter and faster. No need to loop if all you do is return the row.
- I use named `IN` parameters, so you don't get confused with the $-notation in the query string. `$1` and `$2` inside the query string refer to the values provided in the `USING` clause, not to the input parameters.
- I change to `SELECT *` as you have to return the whole row to match the declared return type anyway.
- Last but not least: Be sure to consider what the manual has to say about functions declared [`SECURITY DEFINER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY).

#### RETURN TYPE

If you don't want to return the whole row, one convenient possibility is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION select_transactions3(_col text, _val text, _limit int)    
  RETURNS TABLE (invoice_no varchar(125), amount numeric(12,2) AS ...
```

Then you don't have to provide a column definition list with every call and can simplify to:

```
SELECT * FROM select_to_transactions3('invoice_no', '1103300105472', 1);
```

Comment: hi erwin we meet again.. thanks for your answer, your answer was amazing.. it works man..  i have read the security definer documentation, and I've done that, I just grant a specific function for a particular user. and for tips was very cool.. thanks

Comment: hi erwin , i wanna ask again, what if i only need that 2 field?

Comment: @DiazPradiananto: Cool. :) I added some more info about that.

Comment: thanks erwin. may i ask further for this topic? because if i create procedure like that, then i have to create so many procedure for only one table. what if i have to include the group function, or maybe using ilike on where clause. is there any possible way to efficiently my procedures?

Comment: @DiazPradiananto: Not sure what your question is. I suggest you create a new question where you put all the necessary information. That is generally preferable to putting a lot of info into comments. You can always link to this question if the context helps with your next one.

Answer (score 0):

You can query all databases from the server and sort them according to your own database.

```sql
SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableName';
```