# How to iterate over a record when the columns are dynamic

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I have this function in postgres which takes PVH_COLS_DYNA that contains the columns that are going in to the query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DRYNAMIC_DATA_F(PVH_COLS_DYNA VARCHAR) RETURNS numeric AS $$
    DECLARE

      VV_QUERY_DINAMIC VARCHAR;
      VV_ROW_RECORD record;

    BEGIN
                        
    VV_QUERY_DINAMIC:=' SELECT '|| PVH_COLS_DYNA ||' FROM as_detalle_carga WHERE fk_id_carga_cartera = 1234 ;';


    FOR VV_ROW_RECORD IN EXECUTE VV_QUERY_DINAMIC LOOP
            raise notice ' data  % ', VV_ROW_RECORD.???????; 
    END LOOP;

    return 1;
    
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can I get the data from the record variable **VV_ROW_RECORD**, since the columns are dynamic?

```
    VV_ROW_RECORD.1
    VV_ROW_RECORD.?1
    VV_ROW_RECORD.[1]
    VV_ROW_RECORD.?????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference columns like array items, columns have to be referenced by name.

The dynamic part is not getting the row in your example, but referencing each column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_data_f(pvh_cols_dyna text)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _row  as_detalle_carga%ROWTYPE;
   _col  text;
   _data text;
BEGIN

SELECT *
INTO   _row 
FROM   as_detalle_carga
WHERE  fk_id_carga_cartera = 1234;

FOREACH _col IN ARRAY string_to_array(pvh_cols_dyna, ',') 
LOOP
   EXECUTE format('SELECT ($1).%I::text', trim(_col))
   USING   _row
   INTO    _data;

   RAISE NOTICE 'data: % ', _data;
END LOOP;

RETURN 1;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`%I` is an argument to [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT), properly escaping identifiers as needed.
`$1` in the query string for [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) is a parameter filled in by the `USING` clause (not to be confused with function parameters!).

Related answers (with more explanation):

- [Postgres pl/pgsql ERROR: column "column_name" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510946/postgres-pl-pgsql-error-column-column-name-does-not-exist/9511339#9511339)
- [Iterating over integer[] in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214392/plpgsql-iterating-over-integer/10214621#10214621)
- [How to use EXECUTE FORMAT ... USING in postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065271/how-to-use-execute-format-using-in-postgres-function/14066715#14066715)

Comment: Great it works just fine with your example (i added a **for** to the first select to suit my needs), sorry can u explain a little about what `format('SELECT ($1).%I::text', trim(_col))` does and especially **$1** and  **%I**.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: @PaulJava: I added more explanation and links. Be sure to visit the related answers with more explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Erwin, ill be reading the related answers, thanks for adding more explanation!! been looking for answers for over 2 weeks now :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate `record` columns directly. You have to convert it first into something iterable, like [`json`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) or [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html).

```
FOR vv_row_record IN EXECUTE vv_query_dynamic LOOP

    FOR vv_row_record_pairs IN SELECT * FROM json_each(row_to_json(vv_row_record)) LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE ' field "%" in json is % ',
            vv_row_record_pairs.key,
            vv_row_record_pairs.value; 
    END LOOP;

    -- OR

    FOR vv_row_record_pairs IN SELECT * FROM each(hstore(vv_row_record)) LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE ' field "%" in text representation is % ',
            vv_row_record_pairs.key,
            vv_row_record_pairs.value; 
    END LOOP;

END LOOP;
```

Comment: i dont know much about json but i read something about hstore im gonna give it a try and investigate, thanks for repliying!